# Using Git to manage third party developers

Tags: git

We're about to kick off a project in which we will customized a large opensource project. We will have to patch this existing project in a few different ways:

- theming: changing the look & feel, for which the changes will be mostly in one or a few new subdirectories in the existing project directory structure
- extensions: the existing project has a notion of extensions for which the code only touches one or a few new subdirectories in the project directory structure
- core changes: some small changes in the core of the existing project might be required (as few as possible)
- configuration changes: some changes to the existing file in the existing project might be required for example to register the new extension/themes

The existing project releases patches or new versions regularly, we would like to apply these patches and new versions (when it makes sense). We will use one or more 3rd parties to develop the theme and extensions.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to leverage Git to manage this project. We want the 3rd parties to release code on a regular basis (daily? weekly?) so we can monitor progress. Multiple 3rd parties might be developing code at the same time.

I have done a fair amount of research on Git but I'm not sure what the best approach is. I thought [How to manage a Git "upstream" branch and related patches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398072/how-to-manage-a-git-upstream-branch-and-related-patches) was quite interesting and was wondering how to adapt this for our project.

Something like this?

- 'upstream' branch is existing project, new upstream patches applied to this branch
- one branch per theme or extension

Is the Git way to ask the 3rd parties to work off a clone of the main Git repository and to regularly create a pull request which I apply to the appropriate branch of the main repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. This is basically the 'forking' method of git workflow. You have a main repository which is read-only to all but a few chosen candidates. Anyone who wants to contribute forks it and commits code to their own fork. When they want to submit the code to main repo, they send a pull request which contains a list of their commits.

People with write access to main repo can then merge those pull requests which in layman's terms, downloads the commits from fork to the main repo.

A contributor will generally refer to main repo as upstream and their own fork as origin. But these are just the remote names which can be anything else too.

Check out the following article for a better explanation https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/forking-workflow

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I have reviewed the atlassian documentation (which is surprisingly good!), but still have a few questions.

Comment: In particular, in our project the existing project on which we build will evolve independently from our modifications. Let's say we use the 'forking workflow' and we ask the 3rd party developer to create pull requests once they want us to review a piece of work. Once we reviewed the piece of work and are happy with the result, where should we merge it?

If we merge it into our fork of the existing project will future updates to the existing project not become difficult to apply? (the existing project is NOT using Git, they release tar files with the source code or patches on a regular basis)

Comment: Instead, should we keep these seperately developed features/theme in seperate branches? I.e., existing project in 'upstream' and every feature in its own branches?

Comment: I think it's in your interest to contribute the maximum of features to the upstream project to not be obliged to maintain them in the long term which has a big cost and is error prone. That said, the best is to use feature branches to be able to rebase them on each new upstream version (absolutely keep these branches histories linear by using rebase instead of merge if you want to easy your upstream integration in the long term). It's a difficult work that is waiting you ahead so your history must be as perfect as possible, so squash or clean as much as you can...

Comment: But it you don't want to contribute back (and maintain all your changes on the long term), just commit the files of the tar archive in your upstream branch and merge it in your branch(es)

Comment: We're only doing customizations (no enhancements) which will not be relevant to other people, hence no plans to contribute them back (the project would honestly not want them). I think the way forward is clear to me now: upstream branch + per-feature/theme branch, per-feature/theme branch gets rebased when upstream branch is updated (new upstream release). On the deployment server I locally merge the upstream branch with all the relevant features + theme.